# when using a GET method data is coming in console not in HTML

Tags: html, angular, service

I have written my get method inside `ngOnInIt()`. When I am printing data in console it is visible, but when printing in HTML using interpolation, it is returning `[ object object]`

{{filteredCourses}}  ==> [object object]

and when i am using   {{course.category|json}} so here i am getting all values of array ["course" : "database" , "category" : "database" , "length" : "2hr" ] thats how the value is coming

html :-

```
  <div class="courses" fxLayout="row wrap" fxLayoutAlign="center" [@animateStagger]="{value:'50'}">

                <div class="course" *ngFor="let course of filteredCourses"   fxFlex="100" fxFlex.gt-xs="50"
                     fxFlex.gt-sm="33" [ngClass]="course.category" [@animate]="{value:'*',params:{y:'100%'}}">

                    <div class="course-content" fxLayout="column" fxFlex="1 1 auto">

                        <div class="header" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="center center"
                             [ngClass]="course.category + '-bg'">

                            <div class="category" fxFlex>
                                {{course.category|json}}
                            </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Code:
    filteredCourses: any[];

```
this.product_name = getProduct()['name'];
console.log(this.product_name);
this.token = getToken();
this.httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders({ "Authorization": "Bearer " + this.token });

this._httpClient.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/products/info/'+this.product_name+'/',{headers: this.httpHeaders})
        .subscribe(
                    data => {
                        this.product = data; 
                        this.courses = data['cources'];
                        this.filteredCourses = this.courses;
                        console.log(this.filteredCourses);
                    },
                    error => {
                       console.log(error);
                    }
                );
```

Comment: What is the type of the variable filteredCourses? If it is an array of objects/data you need to use ngFor. Please, post the html code too.

Comment: sir i edited my question please review this again

Comment: Seems, your problem is solved by using *ngFor. I didn't find filteredCourses being directly used in string interpolation in the html

Comment: sir here filteredcourses is an array , in this array information of multiple objects are present , when i an accessing filteredcourses  , single value of single object is not coming

Comment: Please console log the filteredCourses and post the output here. Also, edit the post with the exact code with which you are facing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

try using `JSON.stringify(yourObject)` or maybe in certain cases you can use `Object.keys()`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use loop if its an array of object or you might want to print the properties of object individually.

But if you want to see the object `filteredCourses` in template, use `json` pipe.

```
{{filteredCourses | json}}
```

In case you need help to print values using *ngFor or properties, do let us know.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose filteredCourses collection contains an array of objects. So you need to iterate through filteredCourses using ngFor directive to render data in the HTML template.

Like:

```
<ul>
  <li ngFor="let item of filteredCourses">{{item.courseName}}</li>
</ul>
```